# Copy paste chart from excel to outlook but not as image (clickable)

Tags: python, excel, winapi, charts, outlook

I am trying to copy chart from excel to outlook using python win32 but i want it to be clickable for example i can click and select a bar in my chart.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but if you copy a chart from Excel to Outlook using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V, Excel copies a lot of different representations (Bitmap, PNG, JPEG ...) of that chart to the Windows clipboard. On my computer, the representation with name (as of `RegisterClipboardFormat()`) `"Art::GVML ClipFormat"` is the one that causes the diagram in Outlook to be "clickable". It is a ZIP file containing a lot of XML files.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the excel Chart to the clipboard (`ChartObject.Copy`), then paste it in Outlook - retrieve the current editor's Word document (`Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor`) and call `Document.Paste`. Do preserve the clipboard contents before copying to the clipboard and restore after pasting.

Or you can embed directly from a file:

```
strChartName = Workbook.Sheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Name

Document.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
    ClassType:="Excel.Chart", _
    FileName:=strExcelFilePath, _
    LinkToFile:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
    Range:=Nothing, _
    IconFileName:=Nothing, _
    IconIndex:=Nothing, _
    IconLabel:=Nothing, _
    Object:=strChartName
```

Comment: The clipboard belongs to the user, not your program.

Comment: It is easy enough to save/restore the clipboard contents

Comment: It is not. It is instead impossible unless you have a time machine at hand to revive the server that registered contents for [delayed rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-operations#delayed-rendering), which you just nuked. Instinctively, you knew that already, unless *"do perverse the clipboard contents"* is a genuine typo?

Comment: There are quite a few MS APIs (badly designed you can argue) that functioned only through the clipboard. Old Outlook addins, as an example, only allowed to set images on buttons through the clipboard. In 99.9% of the cases clipboard will contain data that can easily be saved/restored - text, image, file, etc.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have tried to adapt your solution for embedding a chart from file, but I get the error `AttributeError: CreateItem.InlineShapes`.

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of your code. Note that `InlineShapes` is a property on the `Word.Document` object, not on `Outlook.MailItem`.